# document.getElementById(s).document.getElementsByClassName error in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, casting

When trying to use this with typescript and angular2

```
document.getElementById(s).document.getElementsByClassName
```

I get this error

> 'Error' message: 'Property 'document' does not exist on type
>   'Element'.' at: '32,56' source: 'ts'

Which I understand this is an error of casting. But I can't find to what I should cast the getElementById so that it has access to the document properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `document` in the middle. The element returned by `getElementById()` has its own `getElementsByClassName()` method.

```
document.getElementById(s).getElementsByClassName(...)
```

Comment: completely right, I miss-read the source https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName